# Adding a button on a new Swift view controller file doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am currently working on a game and want to add a pause button to it. One of my files is so large that it has become very slow and laggy. I'm trying to break up the code into separate files. I made a file named PauseScreen.swift and tried to make the pause button there, but it seems the code never ran. This is what I did:

```
    import Foundation
    import SpriteKit

    var pauseButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

    class Pause: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            let pauseButtonImage = UIImage(named: "Pause")
            pauseButton.setBackgroundImage(pauseButtonImage, forState: .Normal)
            pauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.view!.frame.width / 2 + 190, self.view!.frame.height - 300, 50, 50)
            pauseButton.addTarget(self, action: "pauseButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            pauseButton.alpha = 1.0
            self.view?.addSubview(pauseButton)

        }


func pauseButtonTapped(sender:UIButton!){}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad, the frame of your view is probably CGRectZero. Try printing the frame and seeing what you get. If that's the case, move your code to viewWillAppear.

Also, be very careful hardcoding your button's frame. It could end up off the screen with constants like 300. I suggest using auto layout to alleviate those issues.

Comment: the thing is, the code doesn't even seem to run. I added a println() statement in viewWillAppear and nothing showed up. Also I'm using auto layout now, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Are you using "Pause" in your view controller hierarchy?